# How can I have an 'truly' interactive command in emacs?

Tags: emacs, minibuffer

How would I implement a *bare bones* function that 're-evaluates' with every key-press?  I mean key-press loosely; I'm looking to emulate the behavior of `isearch` and friends.

I would be using this to interactively test XPath expressions against an open nxml-mode buffer using something along the lines of buffer narrowing.  For the purposes of this question though, just a function that calls `message` on whatever is in the minibuffer would be absolutely grand.

Comment: How about?:  `(add-hook 'post-command-hook (lambda () (message "hello-world")))` and add a `t` to the tail end to make it buffer-local and another `t` if you want to append it to the existing functions already assigned to that hook (rather than pre-pending it).

Comment: Here is a link to a strange animal that can be custom tailored, but is not necessarily scalable for other people to use -- more of an in-house job:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23441478/emacs-creating-an-interactive-only-quasi-post-command-hook  The `post-command-hook` is universal, but fires a little too often sometimes for my personal needs.

Answer (score 1):

Depending of what you want, you could cheat and use `isearch-mode`: its third argument (`OP-FUN`) is a function called after each input is processed, and its 5th argument (`WORD`) can be any function that will transform the string typed in isearch into a regexp to look for in the buffer.

For exemble:

```
(defun my-op-fun (string &optional lax)
  (let ((words (split-string string ":")))
    (mapconcat '(lambda (word) 
                  (concat "\\<" (regexp-quote word)))
               words "\\>.*")))

(defun my-isearch-beggining-of-line ()
  (interactive)
  (isearch-mode t t nil t 'my-op-fun))
```

if you type "foo" it will look for a word beginning with "foo", it you type "foo:bar" it will look for the "foo" word followed by some other char then "bar" as the beggining of a word.

Some regexp mastery might be needed to make this work for you.

You could also just look at the source of isearch to see how it is done.